# Many to Many relationship ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

From the image below.

[image]

It can be seen that I have three table User, User_group and group. I am trying to link a user to user_group and Group to user_group in other words link a user to a user_group. Currently in my user model I have the following:

**User.rb**
has_and_belongs_to_many :group

**Group.rb**
has_and_belongs_to_many :user

What I am basically trying to do is import the data into the User_group table. What is the best way around this. Tried searching online and have had no luck.

[image]

Form Layout

The user should be able to assign themselves to a group. When they click update the information entered should be saved to the user_group table

Comment: What is your question? I do not understand your problem. What data do you want to import and why does it not work? More relevant information please.

Comment: What I am trying to do is assign a user to a group, so basically the table user_groups will have user id 1 and group id 1. I have created a user form with a checkbox for specified group i.e admin, managers, team leader. The user should be able to check these boxes and on complete of the registration form the information supplied should be saved into the user_group table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the Rails convention, you should name your tables `users`, `groups` and `groups_users` and change:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :group
has_and_belongs_to_many :user
```

to:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

If you want to keep the table names you described above, you have to do the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'USER'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, :join_table => 'USER_GROUP'
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'GROUP'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => 'USER_GROUP'
end
```

Note that table names are case sensitive. I used upper case, but that probably does not match your situation.